# What registrars support *.onion TLD as a Subject Alternative Name, and how does validation work?

Tags: certificates, tor

I'm interested in obtaining a .onion TLD in my SAN name from a public CA.

Which Public CAs support .onion TLDs and what is the validation process like (e.g. Whois isn't available for Tor)

Update:

Although DigiCert is issuing [.onion certificates for Facebook](https://blog.digicert.com/anonymous-facebook-via-tor/), they have not made a process available to the masses for such a function.

[image]

Comment: All access to *.onion domains happens securely, why would you need a x509 certificate? And what would that win you?

Comment: @Ángel see this: https://blog.torproject.org/blog/facebook-hidden-services-and-https-certs

Comment: Very informative, although that doesn't explain why you want a https cert? Are you going to put the tor cert at a different machine than the https one? IMHO that would be the main reason to do that (in FB case, they probably have a full https-based infrastructure, so it's easier for them that way). IMHO the right thing for the user concept would be to teach the browsers that *.onion is secure (similarly to the current discussions on marking http as insecure in the UI).

Comment: @Ángel My intent is to clearly "associate" a ToR site with a .com TLD.

Comment: Related question: [Is TLS in Tor useless?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/75975/is-tls-in-tor-useless) (tl;dr: for hidden services it is useless)

Comment: Related: [Thread on CABForum list](https://cabforum.org/pipermail/public/2014-October/thread.html#4210) about ".onion"-certs. From what I read there, the CA broke/bent the "Baseline Requirements" rules against non-IANA TLDs, because Facebook was big enough.

Comment: Update: The [CABForum Ballot 144](https://cabforum.org/2015/02/18/ballot-144-validation-rules-dot-onion-names/) has passed. This means that .onion TLDs be legal in the next version of the "Baseline Requirements". (No idea when that next version  will come out.)